# Django POST: CSRF verification failed. Request aborted

Tags: python, django, forms, post, get

I'm trying to create a very simple web app (I'm very new in Django). This app contains (in `index.html`) a form which has to be dedicated to uploading a block of a text. When user clicks on submit, it returns new page called `processed_text` with this text.

The problem is that it works when I use `GET` but when I change `GET` to `POST` (in `html` and `django`) it returns some exception

> Forbidden (403) CSRF verification failed. Request aborted.

And it does not even print 'process_text method' which is in the view.

Here are my codes:

**views.py:**

```
def index(request):
    return render(request,'uploading/index.html')

def process_text(request):
    print 'process_text method'
    if 'text_to_translate_name' in request.POST:
        message = 'OK {}'.format(request.POST['text_to_translate_name'])
    return HttpResponse(message)
```

**index.html:** *without head*

```
<body>
    <h1>Index z TEMPLATES H1</h1>
        <form action="/process_text/" method="post">
            <input type="text" name="text_to_translate_name">
            <input type="submit" value="upload">
        </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**urls.py:**

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index),
    url(r'^process_text/$',views.process_text),
]
```

Do you know where is the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add `{% csrf_token %}` in your form. It inserts a csrf token input field to your form, which is used by Django for security purposes.

So your form looks like -

```
<form action="/process_text/" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="text" name="text_to_translate_name">
    <input type="submit" value="upload">
</form>
```